# Symfony : Error creating form (BirthdayType) and methods note functionning proprely

Tags: php, symfony

I've been trying to create a form that people can create their account in the database.

The form ask for 3 things : 
First name, last name and date of birth (Text in french in the code).

I keep on having these errors :

> Neither the property "startDateTime" nor one of the methods "addStartDateTime()"/"removeStartDateTime()", "setStartDateTime()", "startDateTime()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Candidats".

Is this because i didn't declare my type correctly in the Entity when i created it ?

Here's my entity class :

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Candidats
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="candidats")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Candidats
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="datedenaissance", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datedenaissance;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idcand", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idcand;



    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     *
     * @return Candidats
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set prenom
     *
     * @param string $prenom
     *
     * @return Candidats
     */
    public function setPrenom($prenom)
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prenom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrenom()
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    /**
     * Set datedenaissance
     *
     * @param \DateTime $datedenaissance
     *
     * @return Candidats
     */
    public function setDatedenaissance($datedenaissance)
    {
        $this->datedenaissance = $datedenaissance;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get datedenaissance
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDatedenaissance()
    {
        return $this->datedenaissance;
    }
public function getDateTime()
    {
        return $this->datedenaissance;
    }
    public function getStartDateTime()
    {
        return $this->datedenaissance;
    }
    public function startDateTime()
    {
        return $this->datedenaissance;
    }
    public function isStartDateTime()
    {
        return $this->datedenaissance;
    }
 public function hasStartDateTime()
    {
        return $this->datedenaissance;
    }
    public function addStartDateTime()
    {
        return $this->datedenaissance;
    }
    public function removeStartDateTime()
    {
        return $this->datedenaissance;
    }
public function setStartDateTime()
    {
        return $this->datedenaissance;
    }




    /**
     * Get idcand
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getIdcand()
    {
        return $this->idcand;
    }
}
```

And a snipet of the code in the form creation that i modified :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;

class CandidatsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('startDateTime', BirthdayType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Candidats'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using so many methods which returns the same property? ( `return $this->datedenaissance;` )

Comment: I tried to "patch" (Not classy at all) the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is with your properties names. In your class, there are nom, prenom and datedenaissance. And in the form there are nom, prenom and startDateTime. That's why the form doesn't find the property startDateTime, because it doesn't exist in the class.